# Redirecting of the output of a command to sed fails, by returning an empty string when assigned to a var - Bash Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

new to Shell scripting here and got stuck in a situation which many of you might think silly but here goes :-)

I have this snmpwalk command which I want to run in the shell pipe the results through sed, in order to keep only specific parts of the returned output, and then store the result in a var. Everything works fine until I assign the output of the command to a var, then I get an empty String when I echo it.

The oid:

```
srOID="snmpwalk -v 2c -c allInfo csvm3122 UCD-SNMP-MIB::ssCpuRawUser"
```

then I pipe to sed:

```
echo $($usrOID) | sed 's@^.* @@'
```

It works fine and prints the resulting CpuRawUser load, in this specific case
41070958

The weird thing is that when I assign to a var and echo I get an empty String

```
a=$($usrOID) | sed 's@^.* @@'
echo $a
```

I need the results in a var for further calculations, any help is more than welcome...
Thanks!

Comment: That "works fine" by luck; it's not best-practice syntax, and if your command were even slightly more complex it would behave very, very badly.

Comment: See BashFAQ #50: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Also, BashFAQ #24: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Comment: ...BTW, going the function route also lets you put the pipeline *into* the definition of `usrOID`, rather than having it be something callers are responsible for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a smaller change:

```
# define a function that calls your code
usrOID() { snmpwalk -v 2c -c allInfo csvm3122 UCD-SNMP-MIB::ssCpuRawUser; }

# run that function, and the pipe that modifies its output, in a subshell
a=$(usrOID | sed 's@^.* @@)
```

...but don't do that: There's no point to use `sed` in a way that duplicates bash's built-in string manipulation functionality (if I'm correct in assuming that output is only one line):

```
usrOID() { snmpwalk -v 2c -c allInfo csvm3122 UCD-SNMP-MIB::ssCpuRawUser; }
a=$(usrOID)  # run function and capture its output
a=${a##* }   # delete everything up to the last space
```

---

By the way, if you *do* have multiline output, and thus really do need the `sed` expression or some equivalent, why not put it into the function definition itself? (Note that the below is a bit anemic on error handling, discarding the exit status of `snmpwalk` unless the `pipefail` shell option is set).

```
# define a function that calls your code
usrOID() { snmpwalk -v 2c -c allInfo csvm3122 UCD-SNMP-MIB::ssCpuRawUser | sed 's@^.* @@'; }
a=$(usrOID) # ...and call that function.
```

---

As yet another alternative, a function version doing the whitespace stripping natively in bash and being careful about error handling:

```
usrOID() {
  local s # define a local variable

  # capture in a second step, to pass erronious exit status through
  s=$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c allInfo csvm3122 UCD-SNMP-MIB::ssCpuRawUser) || return

  # if no errors occurred (and we didn't return), emit output
  printf '%s\n' "${s##* }" # print only content after last space in same
}

a=$(usrOID)
```

---

To speak to why your original code didn't work: Running a pipeline creates subshells; that is, forked-off copies of the shell that are finished and disappear when the pipeline is complete. Thus, `a=$(usrOID) | sed` runs an assignment on the first side, pipes that assignment into `sed` -- and then both processes, `sed` **and the shell with the assignment in it**, exit; meaning that the assignment didn't occur in any shell that's still left running after the pipeline was complete (Related: The only content you captured with `$()` in the original syntax given is the `snmpwalk` call itself, but not the output from `sed`).

---

The behavior of discarding state of subshells on pipeline exit is described in detail in [BashFAQ #24 ("I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?")](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

The reasons to define a function rather than putting code into a scalar variable are described in [BashFAQ #50 ("I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!")](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Finally, to understand string manipulation in native bash (without `sed` or other external commands), see [BashFAQ #100 ("How do I do string manipulations in bash?")](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100).

Comment: There are a ton of useful but little-used features buried in Bash's parameter expansion mechanism. Well done.

Comment: Yep, followed your advise defined functions for all the OID's I want to use and used parameter expansion for string manipulation, it worked more than great!!! thanks for the help!